# pug file compiled to html does not livereload

Tags: gulp, pug, gulp-watch, browser-sync

In my project folder, I have pug files that are located in `src/pug/*.pug`, one of those files is `index.pug`. When compiled to html, the compiled files are located in `build/templates/*.html`. In the `serve` task, in `browsersync.init()`, I changed the `baseDir` from `./` to `build/templates/` because the compiled `index.html` is located there. The problem is, browsersync livereload does not work; I have to refresh the browser just to see the changes I make in `index.pug`.

Gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        pug = require('gulp-pug'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
        imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('templates', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/pug/*.pug')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/all/'))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('imagemin', () => {
    gulp.src('assets/img/src/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img/dist/'));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['templates', 'styles', 'scripts'], () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'build/templates/'
        },
        notify: false
    });

    gulp.watch('src/pug/*.pug', ['templates']);
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.sass', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('build/templates/index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['imagemin', 'serve']);
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that doesn't work, but I have compared your build file to the official docs, and I came across [this approach from the docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-reload): Instead of watching the HTML files, it watches the source (pug files in your case) and calls `browserSync.reload` after that source compilation task has completed. In your case, the pug line would be replaced by something like this:

```
gulp.watch('src/pug/*.pug', ['templates-watch']);
```

And you would create a new task, called `templates-watch`, that would be defined as follows:

```
gulp.task('templates-watch', ['templates'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});
```